# Table view controller on view controller

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview

I am creating an app in which i want to display a text box and when i enter an word in it ,then it will display the contents from the dictionary which are matching to that word.Now i want to display the list which will generate from my dictionary according to the word entered in text box ,in a table view and that table view should be on the same view controller where i am having the text box.Is it possible to do so. I mean is it possible to create a table view with scrolling option so that user can scroll through the list and then select the word which he wants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Take IBOutlet for UITableView and wire it up. Define its datasource and delegate to your controller. Implement UITableViewDelegate to your controller and override all the methods like cellForRowAtIndex and others.

```
//FilterDataViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface FilterDataViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtFld;

    NSMutableArray *arrSrch;
    NSMutableArray *srchedData;
}
-(IBAction)srchBtnTapped:(id)sender;
@end

//FilterDataViewController.m
#import "FilterDataViewController.h"
@implementation FilterDataViewController

-(IBAction)srchBtnTapped:(id)sender
{
    if(![txtFld.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        [srchedData removeAllObjects];
        for (NSString *allStrings in arrSrch)
        {
            NSComparisonResult result = [allStrings compare:txtFld.text options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [txtFld.text length])];
            if (result == NSOrderedSame)
            {
                [srchedData addObject:allStrings];
            }
        }
        [tblView reloadData];
    }
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    arrSrch = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"One",@"One Two",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four",@"One Five",@"Six",nil];
    srchedData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [srchedData count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [srchedData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Configure the cell.

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: @Christina you can follow http://chris-software.com/index.php/tag/uitableview/ . Still if you require any further help please leave comment I will prepare demo for you and post it.

Comment: so nice of you ,,i really need a help ,,please give me a demo of having a table view and then a text box below it ,,then hard code some values and display them on the table view and this app is for iPAD.please if u have time can u please provide me this....?

Comment: @Christina I apologize for delay. I have edited the answer and pasted code. You just need to take UITableView, UIButton, UITextField on XIB and wire UITableView and UITextField with IBOutlet. Wire up touch up inside event of UIButton. It will work as you required. Only thing is that I have used NSMutableArray here in your case you need to implement same logic for dictionary as you said in your question. Once again apologize for delay.

Answer (score 1):

This is surely possible. Create a View based Application and put both of your table view and Text Field in the same view and you can do what ever you are planning to do.

Comment: you will get the scroll by default.

Comment: can u provide me any sample code if u have somethin related to that or any link if u know...

Comment: this one is so complicated ,,i am a fresher actually ,,it will take lots of time to understand that one